# How to get data from table using "msxml2.xmlhttp"

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RixIu.jpg)I am trying to get data from a webpage https://www.lbma.org.uk/prices-and-data/precious-metal-prices#/table
Seemed simple with all the q and a examples online but I'm flapping around like a kipper and reduced to guessing after much trial and error. Could someone please show where I am going wrong?

The aim,,, my wbook data has always been manually updated regularly so the aim now is to download say the first 10 rows of gold prices only and preferably without the Euro data just date, USD and GBP. Headers are not required either just data.

Here is the HTML and code so far. Errors encountered have been 'Object required' and 'Object doesn't support,,,' etc.

```
Sub Get_Prices()

    Dim sWeb_URL As String
    Dim oHTML_Content As Object, oTbl As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, oTBody As Object
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, arr

    With Sheets(20)
        sWeb_URL = "https://www.lbma.org.uk/prices-and-data/precious-metal-prices#/table"
        Set oHTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

        ''get entire webpage content into HTMLFile Object
        With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
            .Open "GET", sWeb_URL, False
            .send
            oHTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        'Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("-index1")
        'Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementById("-index1")
        'Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementsByClassName("pepper-responsive-table")
        'Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementsByClassName("pepper-responsive-table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)
        'Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementsByClassName("pepper-responsive-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(2)
        Set oTbl = oHTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("tbody")

        For Each tr In oTbl
            c = 1
            For Each td In tr.Cells
                .Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
            r = r + 1
        Next tr
            
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line after this one: `Set oHTML_Content =` - Then check to see what `oHTML_Content` was set to. Is it `Nothing` ?

Comment: For me the Option Explicit statement is a requirement. Turn it on by default in all your macros. Even when using Variant variables. How to turn on Option Explicit by default for all VBA Code Modules? Developer>Visual Basic>Insert>Module>Tools>Options>Require variable declaration>Tick the box>OK
That's it!

Comment: braX - it returns "[HTML Document]".But no matter what identifiers I use, Class, Tag, Id on whichever element there is no content to iterate.

Comment: braX - Interesting post you are pointing me to, I've used "msxml2.xmlhttp" so many times with success. But not here. Will try IE to see what happens.

Comment: user10186832 - I always use Option Explicit to ensure variables are declared.

Comment: The prices are dynamically inserted by JS. They are taken from 2 JSONs. xhr can only load static documents from the server. But it may be possible to access both JSONs with xhr. They are GET queries and at least in the browser I can call them directly. For AM prices: https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_am.json?r=84419867 For PM prices: https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_pm.json?r=796011502 The files contain a long history. But with Tim Hall's JSONConverter you can take what you need: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON. For the parameter r it is uncertain what it stands for.

Comment: To be able to read the contents of JSONs better, you can have them formatted here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Zwenn - Looks like I have some work to do. Thank you very much for the leads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading @Zwenn's comment I wrote the following code and brought the values to the sheet.

```
'THIS PUBLIC FUNCTION IN A MODULE
--------------------------------------------------------
Public Function fetch_prices(ByRef AM, ByRef PM, ByVal afterMonth As String) As String
   Dim c As Integer, a As Long, lb As Integer
   Dim URL() As Variant    ', fileSaveTo() As Variant
   
   'change the files path to any valid local path
   'fileSaveTo = Array(".\AM_PRICES.TXT", ".\PM_PRISES.TXT")
   URL = Array("https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_am.json?r=84419867", _
                      "https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_pm.json?r=796011502")
   lb = LBound(URL)
                      
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
       For c = lb To UBound(URL)
         .Open "GET", URL(c), False
         .send
            'Call WriteToTextFile(fileSaveTo(c), .responseText)
         a = InStrRev(.responseText, afterMonth)
         If a > 0 Then
            If (c = lb) Then
               AM = Mid(.responseText, a)
            Else
               PM = Mid(.responseText, a)
            End If
         End If
      Next
   End With
End Function


'THE PRIVATE SUBs IN THE SHEET MODULE
----------------------------------------------------
Private Sub get_prices(afterTheMont As String)
   Const d = """d"""
   Dim AM As String, PM As String, pa As Long, lb As Long, rb As Long, rowId As Long, cc As Long
   Dim dt As String, values As Variant
   Call fetch_prices(AM, PM, afterTheMont)
   pa = 1: rowId = 3
   
  

    Do
      rowId = rowId + 1
      pa = InStr(pa + 1, AM, d)
      If (pa <= 0) Then Exit Do
      dt = Mid(AM, pa + 5, 10)
      Me.Cells(rowId, 1).Value2 = dt
      lb = InStr(pa, AM, "[")
      If lb > 0 Then
         rb = InStr(pa, AM, "]")
         If rb > 0 Then
            values = Split(Mid(AM, lb + 1, rb - lb - 1), ",")
            For cc = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
               Me.Cells(rowId, cc + 2).Value2 = values(cc)
            Next
         End If
      End If
   Loop
   
   rowId = 3
   Do
      rowId = rowId + 1
      pa = InStr(pa + 1, PM, d)
      If (pa <= 0) Then Exit Do
      dt = Mid(PM, pa + 5, 10)
      Me.Cells(rowId, 5).Value2 = dt
      lb = InStr(pa, PM, "[")
      If lb > 0 Then
         rb = InStr(pa, PM, "]")
         If rb > 0 Then
            values = Split(Mid(PM, lb + 1, rb - lb - 1), ",")
            For cc = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
               Me.Cells(rowId, cc + 6).Value2 = values(cc)
            Next
         End If
      End If
   Loop

   
End Sub

'usage via command button click event
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   'it means show in sheet the prices from the first day exist data of the next month
   Call get_prices("2023-04")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thumbs up from me :-)

Comment: Zwenn - thank you for the info and pointer.

Comment: ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ - Astonishing contribution. So kind of you.

Comment: Looking at the historical values I found that the AM and PM values are out of sync, eg an anomaly is on 24-12-1998 where there is no PM value. So I made a modification by printing the date in front of each AM and AM group because something similar will happen in future

Comment: The LBMA Gold and Silver Prices are not published on certain days. This link provides details of non-publication days https://www.theice.com/iba/lbma-gold-silver-price#publication/

Comment: Prices may be published in the morning but not the afternoon, eg Xmas eve or New Year's eve.

Comment: Hmmm yes it will displace the parsing. Well spotted.